# How do you write foldWhile with the standard library?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

is it possible to write the folowing code with the scala standard library ?

```
def foldWhile[A,B](s: Stream[A])(z: B)(w: B ⇒ Boolean)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B = {
    if(s.isEmpty) z
    else {
        if(w(z)) foldWhile(s.tail)(op(z, s.head))(w)(op)
        else z
    }
}

foldWhile(Stream(1,2,3,4))(0)(_ <= 3)((acc, v) => acc + v)
```

Comment: I'm also curious about other functionnal implementation

Comment: Are you the one who unaccepted my answer, or was that done by someone else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I personally think it is grimey, you can have a return in the middle of a fold:

```
def foldWhile[A,B](s: TraversableOnce[A])(z: B)(w: B ⇒ Boolean)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B = 
  s.foldLeft[B](z)((b,a) ⇒ if(w(b)) op(b,a) else return b)
```

Comment: This is not the optimal answer, I'm not sure what happened here, but my answer which was accepted seems to have been overturned I guess over an apparent conflict of interest although the answer itself is perfectly sound.

Answer (score 2):

```
Stream(1,2,3,4).scanLeft(0){_ + _}.takeWhile(_ <= 3).last
```

**UPDATE 1**

So, funny story, I'm friends with Guillaume (he asked the question before I got to the office) and above is actually what he wants, the bug is in the code in the question.

But if you want the exact logic of the question, you could write something like this:

```
val results = Stream(1,2,3,4).scanLeft(0){_ + _}
val index = results.indexWhere(_ > 3)
results(index)
```

I haven't found a one liner for it yet though.

**UPDATE 2**

```
Stream(1,2,3,4).scanLeft(0){_ + _}.dropWhile(_ <= 3).head
```

Comment: ??? The result of this operation is Int = 3, whereas the original yields Int = 6. How can this be the right answer?

Comment: It's an off by one error due to the exact semantic of what was written in the question. I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve the off by one.

Comment: @LuGo I updated the answer, thx for pointing out the discrepancy between the question and the answer.

Comment: That's a pathetic way of earning reputation.

Comment: @LuGo I think you might have misunderstood. What is pathetic?

Comment: @UndercoverAgent a) arousing pity, esp. through vulnerability or sadness. b) miserably inadequate. c) archaic relating to the emotions.